# adding values within an recordset where the userid is the same php

Tags: php, moodle, recordset

I have a recordset which is returned when I preform a mysql query from a MOODLE database.

An example of what I get:

[image: what I am getting]

What I need to do, is in the loop, calculate 'SCORE' field.  If the score total is less or equal to 1, I must display each row.  If the 'SCORE' exceeds 1, I must only display the records that don't add up to more than 1.

Example:

[image: what I need]

So when I perform the loop and write the records to a csv, this is what I need to display:
(record 3 has been removed).

Is there a way that I can do this using a recordset?

An example (not the actual code, because it is writing to a csv and is confusing) of the code I am using is:

```
foreach ($recordset as $user) {
  echo 'Event Code' . $user->code . '<br />'; 
  echo 'Date' . $user->date. '<br />';
  echo 'UserId' . $user->UserId. '<br />';
  echo 'Fullname' . $user->Fullname. '<br />';
  echo 'Score' . $user->Score. '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if i understood correctly but it seems that you would do something like this:

```
$sum = array();
foreach ($recordset as $user) {

  if(!isset($sum[$user->UserId])) { $sum[$user->UserId] = 0; }
  $sum[$user->UserId] += $user->Score;
  if($sum[$user->UserId] > 1) { continue; }

  echo 'Event Code' . $user->code . '<br />'; 
  echo 'Date' . $user->date. '<br />';
  echo 'UserId' . $user->UserId. '<br />';
  echo 'Fullname' . $user->Fullname. '<br />';
  echo 'Score' . $user->Score. '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scores = 0;

    foreach ($recordset as $user) {
      $scores = $user->Score + $scores;
      if($scores <= 1){
      echo 'Event Code' . $user->code . '<br />'; 
      echo 'Date' . $user->date. '<br />';
      echo 'UserId' . $user->UserId. '<br />';
      echo 'Fullname' . $user->Fullname. '<br />';
      echo 'Score' . $user->Score. '<br />';
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I thought he wants to sum the score of a special user and it should be `$scores <= 1`. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$recordset = array(...);

if(!empty($recordset)) {

  //set the inital user and the score to 0
  $currentUser = $recordset[0]->UserId;
  $score = 0;

  foreach($recordset as $user) {

     if($user->UserId == $currentUser) {
       //if the user is still the same, just add the score...
       $score += $user->Score;
     } else {
       //...else reset the score and set the new user
       $score = 0;
       $currentUser = $user->UserId;
     }

     if ($score <= 1) {
       //output
     } else {
       continue;
     }

  }

}
```

Here's a working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BCSaen